word2vec predicts the same word for all inputs
i build word2vec network with 2 linear layers from pytorch. for every word as an input i consistently train model to predict words before and after, for example: i was visiting my grandma's house, for the word - "visiting", i train model to predict "was", then to predict "my", etc. But after training my model predicts always the same word, as rule the first training word ("visiting" from my example)

